# Key-Error: KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([15.593, 15.577, 15.563], dtype='float64')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to calculate a column, but I get the following error:

```
Key-Error: KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([15.593, 15.577, 15.563], dtype='float64')] are in the [columns]"
```

Where is my error coming from? and how can I fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def absolute_humidity(temp, humidity):
    if df[temp] > 0:
        output = ((610.78 * np.exp((17.08085 * temp) / (234.175 + temp)) * humidity / 100) / (
                462 * (273.1 + temp)) * 1000)
        return output
    else:
        output = ((610.714 * np.exp((22.44294 * temp) / (272.44 + temp)) * humidity / 100) / (
                462 * (272.44 + temp)) * 1000)
        return output


data = {'Date': ['2017-10-18 00:00:00', '2017-10-18 01:00:00', '2017-10-18 02:00:00'],
        'T': [15.593, 15.577, 15.563],
        'rF': [77.8, 77.767, 77.667]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
df = df.set_index('Date')

df['aF'] = absolute_humidity(df['T'], df['rF'])
```

I reduced my code and data to the function. Have also not found any solutions so far.

Thought with apply it might work

```
df['aF'] = df.apply(lambda x: absolute_humidity(x.T, x.rF), axis=1)
```

Comment: I think your issue comes from if `df[temp] > 0 `, as the temp values are not in the index of your df so it is throwing errors

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Unfortunately do not understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring your function like this:

```py
def absolute_humidity(temp, humidity):
    return (
        (
            (610.78 * np.exp((17.08085 * temp) / (234.175 + temp)) * humidity / 100)
            / (462 * (273.1 + temp))
            * 1000
        )
        if temp > 0  # instead of df["temp"] > 0 in your code
        else (
            (610.714 * np.exp((22.44294 * temp) / (272.44 + temp)) * humidity / 100)
            / (462 * (272.44 + temp))
            * 1000
        )
    )
```

And assign the new "aF" column like this:

```py
df["aF"] = [
    absolute_humidity(temp, humidity) for temp, humidity in zip(df["T"], df["rF"])
]
```

So that:

```py
print(df)
# Output
                          T      rF         aF
Date
2017-10-18 00:00:00  15.593  77.800  10.349011
2017-10-18 01:00:00  15.577  77.767  10.334587
2017-10-18 02:00:00  15.563  77.667  10.312535
```